# Axios POST request not working when passed object

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to do a post request in a vue js app using axios to a local API and the response is returning empty data. The post request on API is working fine using Postman tool. Below is my code

```
var the_data = {
    title: 'This is title',
    description: 'this is description'
}

axios.post('/api/snippets/insert', the_data)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

On the API end, I am using a simple PHP script and printing whole $_POST request data using this code

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

But this is returning empty array.

Comment: I was running into this as well. Axios does not send the POST data in the form you're expecting. You need something like https://github.com/ljharb/qs and then use `axios.post('/api/snippets/insert', qs.stringify(the_data))`

Comment: Yeah I just checked that. But how to use qs if I am just using vue externally and not like proper vue cli app?

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/qs

Comment: Tried already. But how to create qs object? We can't do require in normal js

Comment: Turns out it's not supposed to be used the old-fashioned way. I'd suggest you go with `JSON.stringify(the_data)` or, if that doesn't work, good old jQuery `$.param(the_data)` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: Damn, I was using jquery all the time but didn't know about $.params lolz. Thank You very much. Life saved :D

Comment: Add it to answers section so I can mark as answered

Comment: This proves qs developer intentionally discourages use via CDN: https://github.com/ljharb/qs/issues/244

Comment: CDN should work and create `Qs` object, not `qs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running into this as well. Axios does not send the POST data in the form you're expecting. You need something like http://github.com/ljharb/qs and then use `axios.post('/api/snippets/insert', Qs.stringify(the_data))`. Please note this build on cdnjs uses `Qs`, not `qs`.

Alternatives to `qs` would be e.g. `JSON.stringify()` or jQuery's `$.param()`.

Comment: I have a rails server pulling in the data, I am getting it in this form using , {"{\"name\":\"moo\",\"dob\":\"5/10/2012\",\"street\":\"123 street\",\"apt_number\":\"\",\"city_state_zip\":\"moo moo\",\"email\":\"moo@moo.com\",\"home_phone\":\"123-456-7890\"}"=>nil}
**axios.post('http://localhost:3000/disclosure_forms', JSON.stringify(this.form), 'json')**

Comment: only Qs.stringify works. JSON.stringify() is not working. Not sure why.

Comment: I too have been struggling with `JSON.stringify()` and keep getting an empty array. I'll give Qs.stringify a try

Comment: Using qs still didn't work for me. I ended up adding `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");` into my PHP script and was able to get the data