# http post request params contains empty array value which will be removed by axios

Tags: javascript, http, object, post, axios

my axios:

```
const axiosIns = axios.create({
timeout: 60000,
responseType: 'json',
transformRequest: [data => qs.stringify(data)],
  headers: {
    'x-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
  },
})
```

and my post data:

```
{
  list: [],
  word: "t",
  condition: {
    items: []
  },
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIRzp.png)

but, in chrome network request, I find that the post data empty values and keys are removed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dhb0.png)

```
Form Data:
  word: t
```

Why and where the fault?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44799589/834309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48839798/834309) is a similar question.

Comment: @fragmentedreality -  Neither of those two posts are related to this poster's question.